# There must be a good introductory numerical analysis course out there!

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, soft-question

**Background** As a numerical analyst, I've frequently taught the 'Introductory Numerical Analysis' class. Such courses are found in many major universities; the audience typically consists of reluctant engineering majors and some majors of mathematics.

The structure of the course is very similar in many of the institutions whose syllabi I've looked at: one begins with finite-precision arithmetic, then fixed-point methods for root-finding (usually 1-D problems),interpolation by polynomials, quadrature, numerical differentiation, some standard ODE methods, and perhaps some finite difference methods for PDE. Any rationale for this particular sequence of topics is obscured in the course.

The truly deep and interesting aspects - approximation theory, error analysis, computational complexity - are either not discussed, or not dwelt on. Instead, the typical introductory course is a collection of algorithms for problems which seem contrived. 
This is a pity. The stronger mathematics student comes away believing numerical analysis is boring and shallow, and the engineer  comes away thinking mathematics has nothing to offer a real problem.

**The question:**  Are there examples (links to course outlines or course webpages preferred) of introductory numerical analysis courses which avoid the above-described tedium, and which have a history of attracting strong mathematics students?

**The constraints:**   The courses should be aimed at students with a background in multivariate calculus, linear algebra, undergraduate dynamical systems and PDE.  One example per answer, please.

**The motivation:** The eventual goal is to compile such a list, and based on these courses suggest a better curriculum at my institution.

Comment: I am not really qualified to judge, but do any of the notes at http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/na/na.html do some of what you hope for?

Comment: Thanks- the notes by Iserles are indeed lovely, and are aimed at the students preparing for the Cambridge Tripos. 
 

Comment: Is it the case that all the "truly deep and interesting aspects" of numerical analysis are too complicated, or long, to explain in an ordinary course? e.g. how do meteorologists/computational physicists/etc. solve huge systems of equations? Is it really just using the same algorithms that we see in the books, but with expensive supercomputers, or are there fundamentally better techniques which are too difficult to cover?

Comment: Zen, I'd aver that some deep ideas are well within the reach of these students. For example, most of them have seen Fourier series in their PDE courses, and are thus familiar with notions of projection and convergence. Orthogonality is also familiar as a concept. A numerical analysis course would be a neat place to introduce the importance of these notions in the construction of algorithms. There are indeed fundamentally better algorithms out there, some of which we *should* be introducing earlier. Why wait before describing the FFT?

Comment: One problem in teaching such courses is that neither group (engineering students or mathematics majors) is likely to have an adequate background in computer science.  This makes it extremely difficult if not impossible to talk about computational complexity in such a course.  It also makes it hard to do much practical work on problems of real world size and scope.  


Comment: Did you have a look to M.Schatzman's book ? By teh way, I disaggree with your statement that "any rationale ... is obscure". At least, root-finding,interpolation by polynomials, quadrature, numerical differentiation must be taught in this order because each topic uses the previous ones.

Comment: Dear Denis, I should edit my question to read: 'any rationale for .... is obscured in the course'. For instance, root-finding does not seem explicitly used in the algorithms for interpolation. Newton's interpolatory polynomials could be used to derive differencing formulae, but instead the latter are typically introduced via Taylor series. One could introduce the ODE methods directly after numerical integration and interpolation, postponing quadrature until discussions of measures of error and reconstruction. 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

John Hubbard tends to take sort of the opposite track, in that he likes to bring a more serious numerical analysis perspective into the 1st and 2nd courses on calculus and differential equations, rather than assuming the students come out of a standard service-stream calculus, differential equations, linear algebra sequence of courses.  Usually this includes a discussion of various ways of representing numbers on computers, like floating-point numbers, round-off errors, perhaps even topics like interval arithmatic.

For example, once the idea of ODEs are set up he likes to talk about "fences".  I don't know if this is standard terminology anywhere or just his, but it's basically like a Lyapanov function but for time-dependent ODEs.  So it gives you regions that trap orbits, but the region may move with time.  He gets students used to thinking in this way gradually, by cooking up fences in the 1-dimensional time-dependent ODE case first.  Then he moves on to things like the Gronwall inequality, applying it for things like the Euler approximations to ODE solutions to observe error growth rates. He also proves Kantorovich's theorem, which he uses for the implicit and inverse function theorems.  He has quite a lot of success getting 1st and 2nd year physics and engineering students thinking about these things.  But it's known as the "challenging" calculus stream at Cornell, and less ambitious students have other options.  I don't know what their numbers are now, but when I was a TA for the course I think he was getting around 80 students per year in the course.

Comment: This sounds like a fantastic way to introduce the subject. Do you happen to recall the course number?

Comment: Humm, it looks like their course numbers may have changed since I was last there.  But from a scan of their webpages it looks like the new course number is Math 2240.  See: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hubbard/vectorcalculus.html also he frequently brings in ODEs material from his books with Beverly West. 

Answer (score 12):

I believe our Numerics course was very interesting. Basically we had the reverse order of the structure in your example.

**Numerics (1-Year-Course)**

1. Motivational example, heat transfer between two Points. We discretized the Problem and derived a way to solve it (1-dimensional FDM). From this, we then moved on to multiple dimensions and time dependency (FTCS, etc..), introducing error estimates along the way.
2. As obviously each problem boils down to linear equations, we looked at a few of the different iterative algorithms (Gradient, CG, Multigrid...) and of course error estimates and Matrix conditions.
3. We then went on to Interpolation methods, Splines and Co., to replace our linear Ansatz from before.
4. Next, we looked at Quadrature. Even without motivation, it was clear to us that this was usefull
5. At this point, we were able to take short detours and look at different other fields of Numerics briefly, for example, Finite Volume Method. We also took a look at things we had left out, like Newton Method (alot of which were introduced in other lectures).
6. We finalized the course with the Finite Element Method (as this is a core research field at our University), starting with Ritz-Galerkin and ending at a-posteriori error estimates. (Althoug this would need some basic knowledge in Functional Analysis)

I'm the kind of student that will follow a lecture with alot of interest if there is a strong/reasonable motivation behind it. Or at least some sort of "big-picture".

Perhaps to your liking, we had a heavy emphasize on Error estimates. We had alot of real life/hands on examples in between highlighting how important this is.  (http://www.ima.umn.edu/~arnold/disasters/sleipner.html)

Further, I have to point out (as briefly mentioned in point 5), that alot of things were already introduced in some other lectures. Mainly our physics lectures required some basic Numerics, so this was not a complete introduction to Numerics.

Comment: You lament that the notes are in German, and then don't provide a link. Are they on the web? Reading German should be tractable for anyone who knows the subject and just wants another perspective. 

Comment: Sadly I only have them in printed form, I'll remove that note from my answer.

Comment: Michael, this course certainly sounds very interesting! I can read German - would you mind posting a link to the course website? And what references did you use?
 

Comment: Here is a list of references we used: http://www.unibw.de/bauv1/lehre/infnumerik/material

The structure of the lecture has changed since I've heard it though: 
Part 1) http://www.unibw.de/bauv1/lehre/numerik1me/index_html (More precisely this: http://www.unibw.de/bauv1/lehre/numerik1me/ergaenzung)

Part 2) http://www.unibw.de/bauv1/lehre/infnumerik

Comment: Danke sehr, Michael
!

Answer (score 8):

When I took a course on numerical analysis a couple of years ago I very much liked the book "[An introduction to numerical analysis](http://books.google.nl/books?id=hj9weaqJTbQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=introduction+to+numerical+analysis&hl=nl&ei=D2PVTdzyOYKAOp70uIsM&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false)" by Suli and Mayers, it is very clear and concise. In particular it contains a lot of rigorous error estimates.

Comment: Thanks- I know and like the book a lot! What would be useful is a link to a one-semester undergraduate course based on it. 

Comment: The course website is http://staff.science.uva.nl/~rstevens/numwisk12010.html
It's in Dutch but it contains the numbers of the sections covered.

The parts of the course I liked most were Gauss quadrature and the Runge phenomenon.

Comment: Both Gaussian quadrature and the Runge phenomenon are great to include, for many reasons. I also like to first present an example and then prove, the excellent performance of the Trapezoidal rule on smooth periodic functions, when integrating over the period. For example, $\int_0^{2\pi} \exp{cos(x)} \,dx$ is approximated well, but $\int_0^{\pi} \exp{cos(x)} \,dx$ is not.

Answer (score 5):

If you haven't, go to the library and take a look at this book: 
"Numerical Analysis: A Mathematical Introduction", Michelle Schatzman.

It will give you some ideas how to make students fall in love with numerical analysis.

Comment: There are lots of excellent books out there, but unfortunately the standard undergraduate NA course in North America is not. Do you know if someone's used the Schatzman book in a course?

Comment: Sorry, I do not. I just thought it would help to have this at your side if you are going to construct such a course. 

Answer (score 4):

I'm teaching within the MPhil for Scientific Computing at the University of Cambridge. http://www.csc.cam.ac.uk/academic/MPhilSciComp
It has become very popular, but places are limited. So we can be very selective with our students. In March 2016 there will be a book published by CRC Press called "A Concise Introduction to Numerical Analysis" based on the Numerical Analysis lectures of the course.

Comment: Do you have any links to the current version of the notes?

Comment: PS I suspect your comment may have been mistaken for spam

Comment: Can you describe the content of the course (in particular, does it avoid the tedium the OP describes, and what deep/interesting material does it cover)? Right now I don't think this is an answer to the question.

Comment: Looking at the initial comments, I see that back in 2011 I mentioned the Maths Tripos notes in Numerical Analysis (written by Iserles originally?)

Comment: The course content can be found here http://www.csc.cam.ac.uk/academic/MPhilSciComp/taughtelement/corelectures. We try to show the underlying principles why an algorithm works. For example we look at butcher trees to determine the order of Runge-Kutta methods.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is too late - but I'd be happy to offer some resources.

I was taking a mandatory grad level numerical methods course last year - but my research is in fact "engineering education". So I spent some time researching (first of all what the heck is the purpose of numerical methods, because obviously I missed that in my undergrad intro course to numerical methods) and then searching interesting ways that numerical methods courses could be taught.

1. Firstly - I will emphasize the extreme importance regularly reminding students what the main point of numerical methods is. Sometimes they will get lost in the math, and forget about the whole point of the course. Regularly remind your students the point of numerical methods vs. analytical methods. Otherwise the knowledge will go at the wayside if they get to know how to jump through quiz "hoops" but really have no context of what the heck the purpose of the course is in their big picture. Check out this info: crosscuttingconcepts site, click articles and "introduction to numerical methods".
2. Really interesting ways of giving lessons!

   -Design a car, and numerical configure how it operates, gear ratios etc as the course progresses (using introductory topics), also the mind map is amazing. Great paper and course designed by Coller and Scott 2009  -niu.edu/assessment/committees/CAN/PresentationsPapersArticles/coller-scott-2009-computers-and-education.pdf

   -Motivational elements/examples. How Disney uses numerical methods (maybe higher level) to model life situations... search disney animations, click technology to see how they used numerical methods in the movie frozen.

   -All courses like "numerical methods" have a culture and traditional structure (referred to as signature pedagogies). In this book "Exploring Signature Pedagogies: Approaches to Teaching ... " - and you find numerical methods in the computer science section (pg 250) You can see a few recommendations for new ways to adapt the education of topics like this (like "an expectation for interactivity and application to their world").Look at using programming to let them in real time engage in the course material with a wow factor. Good possible platforms may be WebGL, or consult with comp sci visualization faculty. Search "chrome experiments" so see those amazing ways of using numerical methods.

Lauren Jatana

Answer (score 3):

Numerical analysis is a big subject... Stephen Boyd's Convex Optimization (available for download on his web page, or in two pound form from CUP) is a very lucid book, covering both applications and theory.

Comment: Indeed, Igor, numerical analysis is a big field! Analogously, even though analysis is gigantic, the first analysis course usually manages to introduce important ideas in an elegant framework, which we all tend to follow. Thanks for the suggestion of Boyd's book. Do you know of a course designed for undergrads based on this book? The preface describes it as aimed at the introductory graduate level.

Comment: Boyd's webpage: http://stanford.edu/~boyd/ has links to several courses, where a lot of the material relevant to the book is covered. I would love to take part in a an effort to design a nice undergraduate level course on numerical optimization. Also note, that math undergrads who are happy with Python might then be able to benefit from tools like CVX, CVXOPT, CVXMOD, etc.--which can also be used to tackle many of the exercises in Boyd and Vandenberghe's book. I also like Lieven's course material, e.g. http://www.ee.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/ee103.html

Comment: Sorry, I meant to link to: http://www.ee.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/

Comment: Whether the course would be suitable for undergraduates is in the eye of the beholder, but it certainly requires no fancy prerequisites...

Answer (score 3):

I am teaching an experimental offering at UVic that goes part-way to addressing your concerns.

The goal of the course is to get 2nd year students comfortable with writing mathematical software in a high-level computer language.  This semester we are using Python but the specific language is the choice of the instructor.

The main part of the course is about building students' confidence up, writing small scripts to test mathematical ideas.

But along the way we teach them about various elements from numerical analysis and their limitations.  We largely do not teach *any* theory in this course.  The course is about learning by example.  So students see first-hand the issues that come from round-off error. They see first-hand arbitrary precision floats and integers, and how they can help (and hinder) an investigation.

We also touch on a variety of topics not specific to numerical analysis.